# custom username with javascript validation

Tags: javascript

I want users to create a username with some conditions.

The username must be 6 or more characters in length.

It can contain an underscore but it's not required.

It can contain a-z or A-Z or 0-9 characters.

currently, this is what I put for validation

```
var usern=  /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,}[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*$/;
```

but the username is not working if it is joseph_123, joseph123_ or jose123

Comment: Your current regex reads something like "6 or more digits, letters, or underscores followed by 1 or more letters followed by 0 or more digits". https://regex101.com/ is a great utility for understanding your regex patterns (don't forget to select ECMAScript/Javascript before starting)

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,}

Comment: If you have an answer, definitely post it as one. I kind of wonder if `______` is a valid username though according to OP's criteria.

Comment: @sojin this really worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\w` *Metacharacter*. Matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the _ (underscore).

`^\w{6,}$`

```js
const TESTS = ['joseph_123', 'joseph123_', 'jose123' ,'1234', 'á123456', '1223456á', 'abc-def']

TESTS.forEach((uname) => {
  console.info(uname + ': ' + uname.match(/^\w{6,}$/))
})
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp